# UPDATE table on JOIN with duplicate values is only returning first value

Tags: mysql, sql

When I try to import values from one table to another table, I don't get all the results. Example, see code below, where I ask to:

```
JOIN transaction ON transaction.invoice = invoicing.invoice
```

Sometimes, I have 2 or 3 invoices with the same invoice number and the UPDATE only happens on the first invoice number, skips the others with same invoice number.

I need all invoices, including duplicates.

```
UPDATE invoicing
JOIN transaction ON transaction.invoice = invoicing.invoice
SET invoicing.raison = transaction.transaction, invoicing.description = 
transaction.description, invoicing.voyage_passenger = transaction.voyage_passenger
```

What am I missing?

**EDIT:**

Table Transaction:

```
|num    |date           |invoice    |type   |transaction    |amount   |description  
|886051 |1375381803     |859532     |A      |carte          |7.00     |bla bla desc1
|886052 |1375381809     |859532     |P      |repro          |0.00     |bla bla desc2
```

Table Invoicing - has approx 8 more columns than table above not noted below.
Again, I just need the info from the 2nd row above to also be included into the table below in a new row.  I also realize now that I should need an INSERT rather than UPDATE to insert these duplicate rows.

```
|num    |date           |invoice    |type   |raison |amount   |description   |clientID
|951100 |1375381803     |859532     |A      |carte  |7.00     |bla bla desc1 |121212
|951101 |1375401111     |859533     |A      |carte  |7.00     |bla different |222444
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Change your update query to a select query.  That will help you see what is causing your unexpected results.

Comment: Do you have duplicates in `invoicing` or in `transaction`? Some table data examples would be helpful.

Comment: Best guess: you have several rows in transaction that match a single row in invoicing.  You are expecting this query to add the new rows to invoicing, but `update` doesn't do that. You would need to `insert` new rows.

Comment: valex, the duplicates are in 'transaction' and I need those duplicates in the invoicing tables.  It is just the invoice number which is the same, the rest of the data within that row is different than the first invoice with the same number. hmm does that make sense?

Comment: dan, what you are saying makes sense of course, simple logic which I overlooked.  However, my table is already created, do you have any idea how I can import / insert only the duplicates of the original invoice number?  By this, I mean, I can't reinsert values which appear only once, nor the first row of duplicate rows.

Comment: @MathieuGingras: `UPDATE` doesn't append records to the table so I think you need Insert new rows but it's not clear what you have do with existing records in the `invoicing` table. Could you add some example data and results you need.

Comment: @valex example data edited in code above in original question.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know what to do with `ClientId`. According your sample data invoice can be in different dates so I'm not sure if ClientId is the same for the different dates invoice.

```
insert into invoicing (`num`, `date`, `invoice`, `type`, 
                       `raison`, `amount`, `description`)
select `num`, `date`, `invoice`, `type`, `transaction`, `amount`, `description`
from Transaction t
where not exists
( select `num` from invoicing i
  where 
       i.`num`=t.`num`
   and i.`date`=t.`date`
   and i.`invoice`=t.`invoice`
   and i.`type`=t.`type` 
   and i.`raison`=t.`transaction` 
   and i.`amount`=t.`amount`  
   and i.`description`=t.`description`  

 )
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/44e3b2/1)

Comment: I like this, the idea works, however made me realize other mistakes I did when I originally created the table and must look for new solutions now.  You got me thinking and that's a good thing ;)

Answer (score 0):

The invoice number in the first table in the join probably doesn't exist in the second table.Why not a LEFT JOIN?